# What is a Carry Propagate Adder?

Tags: adder

It's in my syllabus but there's no mention of it in my book. Can someone explain to me what is a Carry Propagate Adder?

Comment: Maybe it’s the carry lookahead adder. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry-lookahead_adder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carry-Propagate Adder is a simple Ripple Carry Adder according to [this paper](http://www.ece.ubc.ca/~stevew/515/handouts/arith.pdf):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They're probably using the term to distinguish a standard ripple carry architecture from a "carry look-ahead adder."  The look-ahead system is a way to calculate the carry without waiting for it to ripple through a full adder chain.